# Audio plays in all browsers but Safari desktop

Tags: javascript, jquery, createjs, soundjs

I have an issue with Safari desktop. This snippet of code works even on the mobile version of Safari just not on the desktop version (12.1).

js

```
var targetBeep = "targetBeep";
var atmos = "atmos";

createjs.Sound.registerSound("targetBeep.mp3", targetBeep);
createjs.Sound.registerSound("25372639_dark-tension-atmosphere_by_umcsound_preview.mp3", atmos);

$( ".play" ).css({'cursor': 'pointer'}).click(function() {
  setTimeout(function () {
  createjs.Sound.play(atmos);
  }, 2000);
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="play">
  play
</div>

<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js'></script>
<script src="https://code.createjs.com/1.0.0/createjs.min.js"></script>
```

Is it a problem with the code or is it Safari desktop? If its Safari what can I do to resolve this

```js
var atmos = "atmos";

createjs.Sound.registerSound("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/12/03may2020-tobefree.mp3", atmos);

$(".play").css({
  'cursor': 'pointer'
}).click(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    createjs.Sound.play(atmos);
  }, 2000);
});
```

```html
<div class="play">
  play
</div>

<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js'></script>
<script src="https://code.createjs.com/1.0.0/createjs.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: _"I have an issue with Safari desktop"_... you're not alone. Are there any errors reported in the dev tools console?

Comment: I don't think so, I have added to the log after its supposed to play and it shows the message so its running just not working

Comment: I have amended the post

Comment: I added a runnable snippet to your question and confirmed it doesn't work for me either, Safari 15.1. Works fine in Chrome and Firefox

Comment: I would really like to use jquery for clickable assets. I have tried doing it vanilla and it works but it isn't what I want. Thanks for the snippet

Comment: Have you tried without the `setTimeout`? There may be some media control restrictions coming in to play. If it still doesn't work, I'd try raising a bug report with SoundJS

Comment: You can simply add `createjs.Sound.play(atmos).stop();` in the `click()` handler (outside of the setTimeout).